# @Html.ActionLink using image instead of link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

QQ:  Is it possible to display an image via @Html.ActionLink helper instead of a link but be able to pass in object htmlattributes such as item id's?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.TheId })
```

Comment: See: [Action Image MVC3 Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO, ActionLink HTML helper does not support this by default. You can implement your own HTML helper that would do this for you.

Comment: thanks....I had to hack temp it with:             <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.Id } )">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/themes/base/images/Edit.gif")" 
                 alt="" title="Edit" class="icon" /></a>

Comment: Yep, that works too :) See whether you can come with something on the lines of @Html.ImageActionLink("Title", "Action", "Controller", "ImagePath", new { id = Model.Id });