# T4MVC Html.BeginForm with multiple input submits

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, t4mvc, html.beginform, input-button-image

The controller ...

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult PickAColour(ColourModel model, 
                                        string imgbtn, string returnUrl) {
```

and the view ...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Home.PickAColour(Model,"",(string)ViewBag.ReturnUrl))) {
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
    ...
    ...
    <p>Now pick a colour</p>
    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="@Links.Content.Images.A_png" value="A"/>
    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="@Links.Content.Images.B_png" value="B"/>
    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="@Links.Content.Images.C_png" value="C"/>
    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="@Links.Content.Images.D_png" value="D"/>
    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="@Links.Content.Images.E_png" value="E"/>
    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="@Links.Content.Images.F_png" value="F"/>
}
```

Now, this won't work because I didn't pass imgbtn parameter into the method. I don't know what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the correct method overload:

```
@Html.BeginForm(MVC.Home.ActionNames.PickAColour, MVC.Home.Name,
                new { imgbtn = "", returnUrl = (string)ViewBag.ReturnUrl },
                FormMethod.Post, null)
```

As for the complex model object `Model`, you can't pass it using a route value like above. This one should be submitted when clicking a submit button so that ASP.NET MVC Model Binder can do its work.

Comment: I did a test using your way, it runs, but still string imgbtn=null when debug is entering the PickAColour method. Seems like the same result as my original method call?

Comment: Also, by the way, the Model object actually goes well either way, returnUrl is also good. Only imgbtn parameter doesn't seem to connect up.

Comment: Try changing the name of this parameter to make a test... Give an id="imgbtn" for the inputs and try again.

Comment: Confirmed. image button type="image" is causing the problem. MVC can only regonise type="submit" as a button can parse its value. WTH?! didn't know this. Is there a way to get around it using my colourful buttons, instead of boring window gray buttons?

Comment: Here's a possibility I used in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4896439/114029

Comment: Cool. Thanks, I will play around with the CSS :) the logic works now.