# How to introduce static value in View - C# MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my main view i have following:

```
<body style="background-image: url(../Content/themes/base/images/sos.png)">
```

Instead of using string url here i want admin to have access to this url by using AdminModel. Something like this:

```
<body style="background-image: @AdminModel.BackgroundImage>
```

My AdminModel currently look like this:

```
public class AdminModel
    {
        public int DateId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string BackgroundPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Where DateId and Date are fields of a DateTime table. I dont want to add BackgroundPath as a table field because it will only carry one value. So is there a better way to achieve this? So that admin can change background url when they want to?

Comment: so, where do you imagine this field would be persisted if you don't want it to be a table field.? seems to me that you should really be saving this to the db, rather than trying all sorts of exotic solutions (saving to xml, texfiles, memory cache -shudder etc) to work around that very practice.!

Comment: jim tollan - So you think i should create another table with one field in it called BackgroundImage? That is what i was thinking but was not sure if this was right approach to create a whole table just for one field with one value in it?

Comment: yeah, i think you should think out the entire admin requirement and have a table for anything that may be required thee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use something very similar to this:

```
<body style="background-image: url(@(AdminModel.BackgroundImage))">
```

On the other hand, you might want to use *better* (subjective) solution presented here:
[Action Image MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor)

Hope this helps