# Html.ActionLink() image background mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, html.actionlink

How to set an image background for a `Html.ActionLink()`?

My code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {@data_transition = "slide"})
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor

Comment: This works great in MVC3. Thank you! <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/myimage.gif")" alt="Home" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `@class = "css-classname"`,
like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", 
                 "Index", 
                 "Home", 
                 new {@data_transition = "slide"}, 
                 new {@class="css-class-name"})
```

and  in .css

```
.css-class-name{
    background-image: your image;
}
```