# Razor can not find my HTML helper

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using VS Express 2012 for the Web. My project is a MVC 4 project.

I am trying to make a helper to create a menu item which is a png image with a label. I pretty much cut and pasted this code:

[Action Image MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor)

When I try to use the helper razor can not find it.

I get this error:

CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'AddMenuItem' and no extension method 'AddMenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/cfsN99tF

I am trying to use this from _Layout.cshtml: http://pastebin.com/5vN8yYCa

I have added the namespace to Web.Config

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    <add namespace="HtmlHelperExtensions" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Which `web.config` have you edited? Because you need to add the namespace to the `web.config` which is inside the `Views` folder. You should also try to add the line: `@using HtmlHelperExtensions` to the top of your `_Layout.cshtml`...

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to add it under the views/Web.config, and then it worked. I am pretty new to ASP.Net MVC so I didn't see there where two separate config files. Feel free to add that as an answer. It is also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It needs to be added to the config file in the Views folder, not the main config.

See this answer:

[How do I import a namespace in Razor View Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page)

Answer (score 18):

you also need to reload your solution

Comment: Thanks but the problem was that I added the namespace to the wrong config file. It needs to be in the one in the Views folder.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to close and then reopen the solution.