# Change a text link to a picture link ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a ToDo list using ASP.NET MVC.

Every record has Action links as *Edit*, *Details* and *Delete*.

I would like to change these links to **.PNG pictures**. How exactly should it be done?

I have tried the following code, but got no luck on it.

```
<td>
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ToDoID}) |
     @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ToDoID })
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/details.png")" height="15" width="15" /> |
     @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ToDoID })
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/delete.png")" height="15" width="15" /> 
</td>
```

Comment: There is a similar question in this post: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor>

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `Html.ActionLink`. one way to achive that is to use CSS .
something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Edit", 
    "Home", 
    null , 
    new { 
        style = "background: url('" + Url.Content("~/images/login_sm.bmp") + "') no-repeat center right; display:block; height:84px; width:264px;" 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a CSS class and add it in the htmlAttributes object.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "Home", null, new { @class="imgLink" })
```

and then create a class in your css file

```
a.imgLink
{
     background: url(../images/details.png) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 15px;
     height: 15px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```