# how to implement click binding on image in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my simple image on which i want to pass id on image click:

```
<img class="pull-right" src="~/assest/image/cross.png" data-bind="attr: { href: unfollowAction }" alt="" />
```

but it is not hitting the controller action method. i am implementing knockout.js here to send id to unfollow action method like this:

```
self.unfollowAction = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/Post/Unfollow?uid=' + data.PostId;
```

Please tell me the exact correct syntax for data-bind in img tag helper.many many thnks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should try something like this:

```
   <a data-bind="attr:{ href: unfollowAction }">
      <img class="pull-right" src="~/assest/images/cross.png" alt="" />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Html Action Image

```
@Html.ActionImage("unfollowAction", new { id = MyId }, "~/Content/Images/Image.bmp", "Edit")
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor) for more details

Comment: how do i add data-bind attribute here ??